# inheritance does not seem to be working

Tags: python, django

I am trying to take out the common code from form_valid() in django CBV. The code is below:

```
class GenericCreate(CreateView):
    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.usercreator = self.request.user
        form.instance.slug = unique_slug(form.instance.headline, Article)
        return super(GenericCreate, self).form_valid(form)

class ArticleCreate(GenericCreate):
    success_url = '/'
    form_class = ArticleForm
    template_name  = "articles/article_form.html"


class OrganizationCreate(GenericCreate):
    success_url = '/'
    form_class = OrganizationForm
    template_name  = "organizations/organization_form.html"

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.pub_date = timezone.now()
        #        form.instance.usercreator = self.request.user # no error if this is uncommented
        return super(GenericCreate, self).form_valid(form)
```

When OrganizationForm is submitted, OrganizationCreate form is processed, but the usercreator does not seem to get set from GenericCreate class... I get the following error:

```
 NOT NULL constraint failed: articles_article.usercreator_id
```

When I force `form.instance.usercreator = self.request.user` in OrganizationCreate.form_valid(), I do not get this error.

It is as if the inheritance is not working. How can I get away with not having to set the createuser explicitly in OrganizationCreate.form_valid() and use the GenericCreate.form_valid()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `super` with the wrong class.  In `OrganizationCreate`, you must call `super(OrganizationCreate, self)`.  The first argument of `super` should be the same as the class in which you are calling it.  The effect of your call is that `GenerticCreate` is skipped in the inheritance hierarchy, so its method is not called.